# on hover show edit icon on right

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some series on un-order lists, wrapped with `<a href="#">Link</a>` I want show edit icon on mouseover of `<a href="#">Link</a>`... how to do that using jquery?

```
<div class="user_welcome_dropDown_wrapper">
     <ul style="padding-left:0; margin-left:0;">
             <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dummy Link</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dummy Link</a></li>
     </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: You have to specify a little more what you mean by "show edit icon", where do you want to place this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check this out;

http://jsfiddle.net/M48tr/3/

```
$("a").hover(function(){

$(this).append("<div>edit</div>")
}, function(){

$(this).children("div").remove();
})
```

Comment: @erimerturk.. though made some tweaks according to my need, but as a whole exactly what I wanted.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you should be using [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) to append and prepend the link to whereever you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('a').mouseenter(function () {
    // show icon here
});
$('a').mouseleave(function () {
    // hide or remove icon here
});
```

If you only want to show the icon for anchor tags with a href attribute of # the `'a[href="#"]'` selector can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

This would basically work the following way:
You have:

```
...
<li><a href="#">Link</a><span class="additional">extra info</span></a></li>
...
```

With the span hidden via CSS:

```
.additional{
display: none;
}
```

and finally the jQuery:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
$(this).next('.additional').show();
},function(){
$(this).next('.additional').hide();
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/hover/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is great for all sorts of things, but might be overkill here. This can easily be pulled off using plain old HTML+CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/AzkPD/

CSS:

```
li {
width: 66px;
}

li:hover {  
background-image:url('http://glyphicons.com/wp-content/themes/glyphicons/images/updates.png');  
background-repeat:no-repeat;  
background-position:right center;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
</ul>​
```